# Flutter send multicast return SocketException: Send failed

Tags: dart, sockets, udp, multicast, multicastsocket

I am using RawDatagramSocket to send multicast on 239.255.255.250 with port 3702
And it return SocketException: Send failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = 0.0.0.0, port = 2000
The problem is only with iOS physical Phone, iOS simulator and Android are fine
My iPhone verions is iPhone SE and iOS version is 16.1.1

here's my code

```
try {
  List<int> dataToSend = codec.encode('some string here')
  udpSocket?.close();
  udpSocket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(
    InternetAddress.anyIPv4,
    2000,
  );
  if (udpSocket != null) {
    udpSocket!.listen(
      (RawSocketEvent event) async {
        if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
          Datagram dg = udpSocket!.receive()!;
          String data = utf8.decode(dg.data);
          print(data);
        }
      },
    );

    udpSocket!.send(
      dataToSend,
      InternetAddress('239.255.255.250'),
      3702,
    );
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

And I also enabled Multicast Networking entitlement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWS4g.png)

And here's my Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
  <string>_http._tcp.</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>Viper Cam will use this permission to discover the camera</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>fetch</string>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Flutter --version

```
Flutter 3.13.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e1e47221e8 (3 months ago) • 2023-08-22 21:43:18 -0700
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
```